# How to change the height of the ImageView?

Tags: android

When I run, three ImageViews appear on the screen.

And when I press each button, the visibility of each ImageView becomes gone.

imageView1, 2, 3 is an image connected to a button.

imageView4 is a rectangle border that surrounds imageView1, 2, 3.

I tried to reduce the height of imageView4 by 100dp when the visibility of imageView1, 2 and 3 becomes gone.

So I tried this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="120dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:tint="@android:color/holo_red_light" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="120dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:tint="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="120dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:tint="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView2"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:text="Button1"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button2"
        android:layout_below="@id/button1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button3"
        android:layout_below="@id/button2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/rectangle"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    Button button1, button2, button3;
    ImageView imageView1, imageView2, imageView3, imageView4;
    boolean b1 = true, b2 = true, b3 = true;
    int height = 350;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);

        imageView1 = findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageView2 = findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        imageView3 = findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        imageView4 = findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                b1 = !b1;
                if (b1) {
                    imageView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    imageView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });

        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                b2 = !b2;
                if (b2) {
                    imageView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    imageView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });

        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                b3 = !b3;
                if (b3) {
                    imageView3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    imageView3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });

        if(!b1) {
            layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300, height - 100);
            imageView4.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }

        if(!b2) {
            layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300, height - 100);
            imageView4.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }

        if(!b3) {
            layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300, height - 100);
            imageView4.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    }
}
```

But imageView4 showed no response.

What should I do?

Plz help me...

Comment: You can change height of a view as : 
LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) imgView.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.height = 20;
textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

Comment: I tried but nothing changed.

Comment: try making you relative layout's height to wrap_content

Comment: @luhai I tried this and it is working perfectly fine. Please check view initialisation or declaration. May be wrong id assigned to the view.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's RelativeLayout.LayoutParams, but it didn't work because of LinearLayout.LayoutParams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` when working with a RelativeLayout.

Retrieving LayoutParams from imageView is a better idea than creating new params each time since there are other parameters like margins/relations which you wish to retain.

Also LayoutParams accept dimensions in pixels not dps.

Replace

```
layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300, height - 100);
imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

with

```
float deltaHeight = 100 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density; // height in pixels
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.height -= (int) deltaHeight;
imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```